# Only last list item gets rendered in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and and APIs in general. My problem is that when I return some data from an API, add it to the state's array, loop over that array and generate a list element of every single item inside that array (via generateList() function), I only get the last list item, even though it maps over more than 1 item.

```
state = { movies: [] };

onTermSubmit = async (term) => {

    //requests

    }).then((response) => {

        for (let i = 0; i<response.data.results.length; i++) {

            this.setState({movies: [{
                id: response.data.results[i].id, 
                title: response.data.results[i].title
            }]})
        }
        this.generateList();
    });
}

generateList = () => {
    return(
    this.state.movies.map(item => (
        <li key={item.id}>{item.title}</li>)
    ))
}

render() {
    return (
    <div className="ui container"> 
        <SearchBar onTermSubmit={this.onTermSubmit} /> 
        // the Results component is an <ul> element
        <Results generateList={this.generateList()} />
    </div>
    )
}
```

As it stands, when I run .map function over the array and return it, I only get the last list item. I would like to receive the whole list and pass it to the Results component.

Comment: You're overwriting with one item (movie) each time, you might think you're adding to the array but you're overwriting it - map the response first to how you want it, then update state with the whole response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see few problems here, it renders your last element because you overwrite previous with every setState in `then()`.

I also reccomend not to call method as `Results` `generateList` property, but instead pass rendered elements as child. If you have any questions feel free to ask. I written it quickly so possibly won't compile because of some typo/syntax.

```
state = { movies: [] };

onTermSubmit = async (term) => {
    //requests

}).then((response) => {

    const movies = response.data.results.map((movie) => {
       return {
         id: movie.id,
         title: movie.title
       }
    })

    this.setState({ movies })
 }

generateList = () => {
   return(
       this.state.movies.map(item => (
       <li key={item.id}>{item.title}</li>)
    ))
}

render() {

    return (
    <div className="ui container"> 
        <SearchBar onTermSubmit={this.onTermSubmit} /> 
        // the Results component is an <ul> element
        <Results>
            {this.generateList()}
        </Results>
    </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I fixed it now. Could you tell why it's better to pass rendered elements as children? Is it an industry standard?

Comment: Thing what you did there is passing children as a property, but name in different way. It's antipattern, children should be nested between opening and closing tags instead.

Answer (score 2):

It has to do with how you parse the result of your API call:

```
 for (let i = 0; i<response.data.results.length; i++) {

        this.setState({movies: [{
            id: response.data.results[i].id, 
            title: response.data.results[i].title
        }]})
    }
```

Here you loop your result and overwrite the `movies` in state with the info of items result.. This will result in you only seeing the last result.

How about:

```
}).then((response) => {
        this.setState({movies: response.data.results.map(item => ({
            id: item.id, 
            title: item.title
        })})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You overwrite the movies object in your state for each result you get, thus only the last movie is added to the state. Read this article for more information on [managing arrays in state](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-state-array-add-update-remove).

Here is a way to do it correctly:

```
const movies = response.data.results.map(result => ({
  id: response.data.results[i].id,
  title: response.data.results[i].title
}));
this.setState({ movies });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your call to setState is only setting the movies: to an array with 1 item each time in the loop, essentially overriding the previous movie.

Also there's a syntax error in your generateList function (an extra ')' at the end of the line with the

)

```
this.setState({movies: response.data.results});
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to loop over the results of your http request. You can just do something like:

this.setState({ movies: response.data.results);